# Print Sobert has duplicate print

Tags: python, duplicates, combinations

Okay I've included my code that I wrote with the issue that when it prints the list I get: You give the pair Banana, Chocolate twice (once as Banana, Chocolate and once as Chocolate, Banana). I did find code that doesn't have this issue but my issue then is I'm not understanding how it's resolving the issue which defeats the purpose.

my code:

```py
FLAVORS = [
    "Banana",
    "Chocolate",
    "Lemon",
    "Pistachio",
    "Raspberry",
    "Strawberry",
    "Vanilla",
]

for x in FLAVORS:
    for y in FLAVORS:
        if x != y:
            print(x + ", " + y)
```

code that works but I dont understand:

```py
FLAVORS = [
    "Banana",
    "Chocolate",
    "Lemon",
    "Pistachio",
    "Raspberry",
    "Strawberry",
    "Vanilla",
]

for flavor_one in FLAVORS:
    for flavor_two in range(FLAVORS.index(flavor_one)+1,len(FLAVORS)):
        print(flavor_one + ", " + FLAVORS[flavor_two])
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay if I understand what you're asking for your code to work you can edit in the below code. So what's happening in the code is you're checking in the range of FLAVORS and then appending the list called FLAVORS to an index. you're pointing the index to "x" and telling it to go up by 1 Then it checks the length of FLAVORS this is where the code confirms that you're not getting chocolate banana and banana chocolate. This all happens in  `range(FLAVORS.index(x)+1,len(FLAVORS)):`  from that point you're printing the first flavor (x), second flavor. `FLAVORS[y]` is pointing back to the previous line when you turned FLAVORS into a index.

additionally here is the syntax for index as I'm assuming that is what threw you off.

syntax    list.index(elmnt)

```py
for x in FLAVORS:
    for y in range(FLAVORS.index(x)+1,len(FLAVORS)):
        if x != y:
            print(x + ", " + FLAVORS[y])
```